# Nomenclature with different groups for IEEE Transactions

Tags: ieeetran, nomenclature

I want to create a Nomenclature for IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy with different groups, such as: Indices, Parameters, Sets and Variables. I have seen that there is a line break between each group and without bold style.

Comment: Is there any news here? You didn't provide any additional information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the job. https://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/

```
\section*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\begin{IEEEdescription}[\IEEEusemathlabelsep\IEEEsetlabelwidth{$V_1,V_2,V_3$}]
\item[$V_1,V_2,V_3$] Three-phase PWM output line voltages.
\item[$\theta$] Rotor angle (in ``electrical degrees'').
\item[$\omega$] Rotor (electrical) speed, corresponding to the time derivative of $\theta$.
\end{IEEEdescription}
```